# How do we point custom object's record owner as approver in salesforce?

Tags: approval-process

Sorry to put my question like this. 
I have a requirement where a consumer need to access fruits produced by producer. 
Consumer, Producer, AccessFruit are three custom objects. AccessFruit object has a lookup field that points to producer.
Now, A producer created a record called Apple.
So, a consumer needs to access Apple. So, a consumer makes a record of type AccessFruit and uses the lookup field that points to Apple record.

When this new AccessFruit record is submitted, the approval process should be initiated and the approval should go to the owner of apple record.
How can i set approver in the Approval Process setting page?

In the approval setting page under, Automatically assign to approver(s), I selected Related user but only createdby, last modified by and owner valuesare shown. I want another field called Product.owner or something like that.

Comment: can you post a picture what you have tried so far

Comment: I will post pictures once i am on my laptop. When i(consumer) create a record then a notification for approval comes to me only (consumer). I want the notification to be sent to the owner of the Producer record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a Lookup (User) field called ProductOwner which will be populated when new AccessFruit record will get created, taking the OwnerId of Producer (Apple record).

Hide this field from the page layout so that user cannot change this.

Secondly, when Owner of the Apple record gets changed, you need to update this field value in AccessFruit record.

In the Approval Process, select this field as `Related User` for approval.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same but haven't tried.